# {name : value} notation for arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do this for a multidimensional array and can't figure out why it doesn't work for a single dimensional array:

```
function doArray() {
   var msg = [];
    msg.push({entryID : "test"});
    alert(msg[entryID]);
}
```

I get undefined when I try to alert it.  What's wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: You're not doing it right: http://jsfiddle.net/CgbTC/

Comment: You should read more about objects: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: You should get a ReferenceError (unless you are not showing all of your code), because `entryID` is not defined.

Comment: And as I said in my previous answer, you should not think about it as multidimensional array. You have an array of objects. The only difference is that here your object only has *one* property instead of several ones. But that does not change the overall structure. I think the link I posted above will help you to understand objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you have to use the index for the array (`[0]`), and then you need to quote the keyname to access the value in the object you've pushed onto the array:

```
function doArray() {
   var msg = [];
    msg.push({entryID : "test"});
    alert(msg[0]['entryID']);
}
doArray();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CgbTC/

Try it with a `console.log(msg)` to see what you actually have:

http://jsfiddle.net/CgbTC/1/

Also, as [tskuzzy notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9351653/451969), you can access using `msg[0].entryID`, as `msg[0]` will give you the object you've added to the array:

http://jsfiddle.net/CgbTC/3/

Answer (score 2):

Because msg is an array whose first element is `{entryID : "test"}`

So you have to reference it like this:

```
alert(msg[0]['entryID']);
```

Or like this:

```
alert(msg[0].entryID);
```